# Forum Spambot for Changing OpenDNS Settings on a Timer

Tags: router, dns, dd-wrt, opendns

I have read again and again the request for OpenDNS to incorporate a time restriction feature. From what I understand, they can't because of something about caching. I loaded DD-WRT firmware on my friend's router and set up time restrictions that way, but the problem is that I can't put every single website restriction in (there are too many game sites out there, for example), and the keyword block doesn't block everything. OpenDNS does an extremely good job at blocking certain subject content.

So what I have been doing is at a certain time, I'll block certain categories, and then at a certain time I'll unblock them again. Obviously, that is a big pain in the butt and it's hard to remember to do this as I go about the business of my day.

So I was thinking... if spambots can sign up for forums and make posts, that means that they can read and write and get through the forum sign up process. What if I created some sort of spambot to block specific categories at a certain time, and to whitelist and blacklist certain websites at a specific time? How would I do this? Would it need to be a program running on my computer? If so, I would have to have my computer on all the time (which I would rather not do). Or could I have it running on some sort of website host and work that way? Essentially, it would be a robot to do what I have been having to do manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: OpenDNS actually do have this feature, unfortunately it is only available if you buy the partnered router from Netgear - http://www.netgear.com/lpc#

Comment: Buying another router is not an option. That is why I wanted to create a bot that can just change the settings for me on a time schedule.